# SWIG unsigned char to byte array c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, swig, uint8t

just playing around SWIG and stucked at typemaps for unsidned char.
I would need the following uint pointer as byte[] in C#.

```
//C++
uint8_t* data;
//C#
ushort[] or byte[] data;
```

For Python I found some ideas how should look like but had no lunk with C# implementation.
Could someone suggest a direction please?
Thanks in advance!

**SOLVED:**

Thanks for the marks for the other question but I dont think its duplicated, coz that is for clear PI/Invoke or DLL import. I am doing this with SWIG and nothing to do with DLL import and pointers (SWIG doing it by itself). But I came up for some sultion if somebody has same issue:
First of all if someone want to give it a try could look into more typemaps:

```
%include "cpointer.i"
//%pointer_cast(unsigned char*,byte, convert_to_array)
```

or

```
%include "carrays.i"
//%array_functions(unsigned char, ushort);
```

Wasnt sure how they supposed to work, so here is my final solution:
made C++ converter for SWIG, coz SWIG translates char* to string or string to string with right library:

C++ converting code

```
std::string ConvertData(uint8_t &data)
{
    char* inner = (char*)malloc(sizeof(data));    
    std::string tmp ;    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++)
    {
        sprintf(inner, "%02X ", data[i]);
        tmp += inner;

    return tmp;
}
```

I needed some formatting too coz its used as HEX at the end. This formatting divides the actual data bytes into 2 characters with capital letter and a white space between them.

When using SWIG interface file add this before your C++ header. This will tell to SWIG to use the std library and use string right. Other option that you use char* instead of string and SWIG also will give back string.

```
%include "std_string.i"
```

Then in C# or any language you can use your string as you wish. I parsed into string array where the white spaces were.

C#

```
string[] tmp = ConvertData(parsedStringFromCPP).Split(' ');
```

Hope helps someone else too. Cheers

Comment: Trying the idea with that pointer solution and marshalling from here, but the problem is SWIG creates SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char out of the uint8_t not even pointer. Anyhow thanks

Comment: The answer to your question should not be a part of the question - it should be an _answer_. Otherwise, the SO system identifies it as "unanswered" even if it's not.  After 48 hours you will also be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I dont have/see the "Answer your question" button, probably because it says its duplicated? Cannot even have link for this question, even I dont think its pair of the other one, and have completly other solution too. But then never mind... cannot help on this more.

Comment: As long as the question is marked as a duplicate, you can't. But if the question is a legitimate one, the hold may be taken away soon.